# Почему AUTO_INCREMENT прибавляет по 10?

Tags: mysql, azure-websites

Приветствую! Создал таблицу, добавляю значения, а вместо прибавления еденицы к значению ID, добавляется сразу по 10. Пробовал менять `auto_increment_increment` (это такая переменная, её советовали поменять на англоязычном stackoverflow) (там стоит 10) на 1, но оно не меняется. Буду крайне благодарен за помощь!

[image: Специально для @Alex]

Comment: @Alex если бы я был уверен, что тут всё зависит от структуры и записей, то я бы добавил это всё. Раньше `auto_increment` в таких же таблицах прибавлял по 1.

Comment: Проверь-ка, что ты не пытаешься выполнить 9 неуспешных транзакций с той же операцией вставки...

Comment: @Alex специально для вас обновил вопрос.

Comment: @Alex `SQL-запрос успешно выполнен.` и `MySQL вернула пустой результат (т.е. ноль строк).`. Я так уже пробовал, но если проверить заново, то там всё ещё 10.

Comment: @Alex я не знаю что это такое, так что едва ли.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30357/discussion-between-alex-and-deff).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для MySql на Windows Azure:

> MySQL в Windows Azure поддерживается ClearDB.

Как мы видим из [FAQ ClearDB](https://www.cleardb.com/developers/help/faq):

> **When I use auto_increment keys (or sequences) in my database, they**
>   **increment by 10 with varying offsets. Why?**
>
> ClearDB uses circular replication to provide master-master MySQL
>   support. As such, certain things such as auto_increment keys (or
>   sequences) must be configured in order for one master not to use the
>   same key as the other, in all cases. We do this by configuring MySQL
>   to skip certain keys, and by enforcing MySQL to use a specific offset
>   for each key used. The reason why we use a value of 10 instead of 2 is
>   for future development.

**Перевод:**

> **Когда я использую auto_increment ключи (или последовательности) в моей**
>   **базе данных, они увеличиваются на 10 с разницей смещения. Почему?**
>
> ClearDB использует циркулярную репликацию для обеспечения поддержки MySQL
>   мастер-мастер. Таким образом некоторые вещи, такие как auto_increment
>   ключи (или последовательности) должны быть настроены в порядке для
>   одного хозяина, чтобы не использовать тот же ключ как с другой
>   стороны, во всех случаях. Мы делаем это путем настройки MySQL
>   пропуска некоторых ключей и путем введения MySQL использования
>   конкретного смещения для каждого используемого ключа. Причина, почему
>   мы используем значение 10 вместо 2 предназначена для будущего развития.

Comment: и что же мне тогда делать?

Comment: @DeFF если это Вам очень мешает, возможно, Вам стоит сменить azure. сейчас очень много провайдеров, в связи с чем можно арендовать vps или выделенный сервер по очень низкой цене.

Comment: ладно, я продумаю над этим. Большое спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @DeFF в данной ситуации есть несколько вариантов:
1) добавить поле user_idn(например) и в него забивать идентификатор id(однако incriment нужно будет делать вручную, что будет загружать бд лишними запросами).
2) добавить таблицу с полями id и user_idn(смысл тот же как и в 1-м случае).
3) можно просто не обращать внимание на отступ в 10. однако, Лично нас бы это напрягало(невозможность корректно выстроить работу auto_incriment).

Comment: Да, меня это тоже напрягает, но в итоге оказалось, что этот ID не столь важен и от него можно избавиться (ну или оставить так как есть, а потом говорить что у меня большая база не из 100, а из 1000 записей :)

Answer (score 0):

По умолчанию, в MySQL значение шага автоинкременты = 1.

Похоже, что конфигурация самого MySQL была изменена.

1. Проверьте, нет ли в конфиге (**my.cnf** для linux и **my.ini** для windows) строки `auto_increment_increment=10`.
2. В стартап скрипте запуска MySQL, нет ли опции `--auto_increment_increment=10`.

Но, даже, в случае с дефолтными значениями в конфигурации, команда

```
SET @@auto_increment_increment=1;
```

должна корректно отработать, и запрос `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'auto_inc%';` должен вернуть следующий результат:
[image: Результат запроса]

Comment: @cache спасибо за ответ, но у меня не меняется с помощью `SET @@auto_increment_increment=1;`, а поменять конфиги mysql я не могу, потому что БД у меня в azure :/

Comment: а А PHP My Admin случайно не переконнекчивается на каждый запрос? Запрос SET @@auto_increment_increment=1; устанавливает переменную из области видимости сессии. Если нет доступа к конфигам, можно попробовать запрос SET GLOBAL auto_increment_increment=1; (нужны права суперюзера)